# Extension field, degree of $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb Q]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I want to calculate the degree of $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb Q]$, can I do like that:

$$X=i+\sqrt{-3}\implies X=i(1+\sqrt{3})\implies X^2=-(1+\sqrt{3})^2\implies X^2=-1-2\sqrt{3}-3\implies X^2+4=\sqrt 3\implies (X^2+4)^2=3\implies X^4+8X^2-13=0$$

Since $p(X)=X^4+8X^2-13$ is irreducible, $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb Q]=4$.

If it's wrong I don't know how to do.

Comment: I didn't check the computations, but if they are correct, you just proved that $[\mathbb Q(i+i\sqrt3)\colon \mathbb Q]=4$.

Answer (score 3):

This shows that the degree of the extension is **at least** $4$.

Now prove the other direction of showing it is at most $4$ (this is the easier direction)

Another way of arguing the correctness would be to prove the element you considered is a primitive element of the extension

Answer (score 2):

What you have proved is that $[\Bbb Q(i+\sqrt{-3}):\Bbb Q]=4$. It is clear that $\Bbb Q(i+\sqrt{-3})\subset \Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{-3})$, but you must prove the converse inclusion.

Comment: Can you tell me why it's clear that $\mathbb Q(i+\sqrt{-3})\subset \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{-3})$ ?

Comment: @idm - Because both $i,\sqrt{-3}\in\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-3})$ and it it closed
under addition (since it is defined to be a field)